# I'm writing function, when in textInput value is written 'giorgi' and in passInput is written 'gio' alert welcome, if not then alert wrong

Tags: javascript

```js
let userName = document.getElementById('textInput').value; 
let userPass = document.getElementById('passInput').value; 
function myFunction(){ 
  if(userName === 'giorgi' && userPass === 'gio'){ 
    alert('Welcome'); 
  } else { 
    alert('Wrong'); 
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: it always alerts wrong

Comment: despite of writing in textinput giorgi

Comment: You only read the inputs once, at that point they're empty. Assigning the input value to a variable does not create a connection, it just assigns whatever string is in the input at the time. If later either of them changes, that does not affect the other at all. You want to read the inputs' values when the user clicks a `login` button.

Comment: so what should I change?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the value of my input always empty if I store it in a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58078160/why-is-the-value-of-my-input-always-empty-if-i-store-it-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only read the inputs once, at that point they're empty. Assigning the input value to a variable does **not** create a connection, it just assigns whatever string is in the input at the time of the assignment being executed. If later either of them changes, that does not affect the other at all.

You want to read the inputs' values when the user clicks a login button.

```js
function login() {
  // notice we're reading and assigning the input values every time this function runs
  let userName = document.getElementById('userName').value;
  let userPass = document.getElementById('userPass').value;
  if (userName === 'giorgi' && userPass === 'gio') {
    alert('Welcome');
  } else {
    alert('Wrong');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type=text id=userName placeholder="Enter Username" />
<input type=password id=userPass placeholder="Enter Password" />
<button type=button onclick=login()>Login</button>
```